# What areas in Tokeet do I need to check when I encounter a missing Booking Engine check out page in preview mode

Tags: web

I am creating a booking engine and before finalizing all the changes, I am checking the preview page. I notice that the check out page on the booking engine shows an error. Where areas do I need to check in Tokeet to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

One of the areas that you need to check in Stripe and make sure that you have signed up for stripe.  If you have signed up, make sure that your account is set to active.  If you have more than one stripe account, you need to make sure that one of them is set to default.  There is a link to a Powerpoint slideshow to walk you through the steps.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QB0fuuCL5XBF-mXTD27qJVznMRB4UGiG/view?usp=sharing